# In eclipse maven dependency jar not showing proper struture like other third part jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, packaging

I am trying to use the one of local project(linkedlist) in another local project(stack). For this I created jar of linkedlist and use depedency in stack. Though I am able to use the my linked list class in stack project. As per below screen shot I had need some doubts and need an help for this.
[image: Project jar]

Under maven depedency you expand linked list jar there is folder inside.
While if you check the junit jar there are package like strcuture.
I need my jar should represent as same as junit.

Please some can help me with this.

Comment: You appear to have everything in the META-INF folder - that looks wrong. It looks like your jar is not built correctly.

Comment: I have add mainClass in pom.xml  to manifest file now it working but as suggested it showing all other thing , as I am new to jar packaging  could you share some refrence to learn this thing.
Thanks in an adavcnce